# A question concerning terminal time

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, stochastic-processes

A terminal time $\tau$ is a stopping time satisfying $$\omega \in \{\tau(\omega) > t\} \text{ implies that } \tau(\omega) = t + \tau(\theta_t\omega), $$ for all $t\ge 0$. Here $\theta_t$ is the shift operator. I am wondering why the first hitting time is a terminal time but the second hitting time is not? Thanks.

Comment: What is in this context $\omega$,$\Omega$? This is needed to understand $\theta_t \omega$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand\om\omega\newcommand\th\theta$Let $\tau$ be the first hitting time of a set $B\subseteq S$, so that for each "path" $\om\colon[0,\infty)\to S$ we have
$$\tau(\om)=\inf\{u\colon u\ge0,\om(u)\in B\}.$$
For each real $t\ge0$, the $t$-shifted path $\th_t\om$ is defined by the formula
$$(\th_t\om)(s):=\om(t+s)$$
for real $s\ge0$.

If now $\tau(\om)\ge t$ for some real $t\ge0$, then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\tau(\om)&=\inf\{u\colon u\ge t,\om(u)\in B\} \\ 
&=\inf\{t+s\colon t+s\ge t,\om(t+s)\in B\} \\ 
&=\inf\{t+s\colon s\ge0,(\th_t\om)(s)\in B\} \\ 
&=t+\inf\{s\colon s\ge0,(\th_t\om)(s)\in B\} \\
&=t+\tau(\th_t\om).
\end{aligned}$$
So, $\tau$ is a terminal time.

---

The second hitting time $\tau_2$ of $B$ is defined by the formula
$$\tau_m(\om)=\inf\{u\colon u>\tau_1(\om),\om(u)\in B\},$$
where $\tau_1$ is the first hitting time of $B$.
Suppose now a path $\om$ visited a set $B$ only at time moments $1$ and $3$, and choose $t=2$. Then $\tau_2(\om)=3$, so that $\tau_2(\om)<\infty$ and $\tau_2(\om)>t$. However, $\tau(\th_t\om)=\infty$ and therefore the condition $\tau(\om)=t+\tau(\th_t\om)$ fails to hold. So, $\tau_2$ is not a terminal time.

Comment: Got it! Many thanks!